# Passing an HTML/Javascript datepicker val to a java servlet using GET: do I have to use a hidden var?

Tags: javascript, jquery, servlets, datepicker

I want to get a user-entered date through jquery's datepicker, send it to a java servlet, and display it. My previous method used HTML dropdowns but I want to use js to select a date. Just using getParameter("date") produces null. Similar questions have been asked and the only solutions I understand is using a hidden variable. But it doesn't make sense that I have to use a hidden variable here. Why does passing dateValue work but not passing date? Or is there a way to pass date directly in the HTML form section?

*Relevant java servlet code:*

```
String stringDate = req.getParameter("date");

out.println(stringDate);
```

*Javascript/HTML code:*

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <TITLE>
        TEST
    </TITLE>
    <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
          $("#datepicker").datepicker({
              changeMonth: true, 
              changeYear: true,
              onSelect: function(){
                  var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
                  document.getElementById("dateValue").value=date;
              }
              });
        });
    </script>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="WHITE">
<TABLE BORDER="2" CELLPADDING="2">
<TR><TD WIDTH="275">

<FORM METHOD="GET" ACTION="myservlet">
    <input id="datepicker"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="dateValue" id="dateValue">
    <INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" VALUE="Calculate dates">
    <INPUT TYPE="RESET">
</FORM>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to name your input field.

Try this, and you can retrieve the value with `req.getParameter("pickedDate");`

As you can see, no need for a hidden input, and then no need to do anything on the select()

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <TITLE>
        TEST
    </TITLE>
    <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
          $("#datepicker").datepicker({
              changeMonth: true, 
              changeYear: true
              });
        });
    </script>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="WHITE">
<TABLE BORDER="2" CELLPADDING="2">
<TR><TD WIDTH="275">

<FORM METHOD="GET" ACTION="myservlet">
    <input id="datepicker" name="pickedDate"/>
    <INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" VALUE="Calculate dates">
    <INPUT TYPE="RESET">
</FORM>

</BODY>
```

[JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Fr9WL/12/)